# handel returned object from dropbix-api (nodejs and express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dropbox-api

i am trying to perform a simple action like upload a file to dropbox,
the file is upload succsfully 
what i need is the returned answer that conatain file name,size,path etc.

i know that i lost in the async calls,
and i would like to get some help here please:

```
exports.uploadFile =  async function () {
    fs.readFile('./text.txt',  function (err, contents) {
                if (err) {
                     console.log('Error: ', err);
                }
                    uploadFile(contents);
            });
          } ;
async function  uploadFile(fileCont) {
         let dbx =  new Dropbox({ accessToken: APP_KEY });
         await dbx.filesUpload({ path: '/basic4.txt', contents: fileCont })
         .then(function (response) {
           console.log( response);
           return response;
         })
        .catch(function (err) {
             console.log(err);
         });
}
```

and i wanted to return the result to fron and so i used this part:

```
DriveService.uploadFile()
    .then((success)=>{
        return res.status(200).json({success:true,data:success,message:'list of files recived'});
})
.catch((error)=>{
    return res.status(400).json({success:false,data:{},message:error.message});
})
```

the problem is that the success is always empty since i got lost in the async forest.

can somone please advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure bout solution in async but, You can use callback like this:

```
exports.uploadFile =  async function (cb) {
    fs.readFile('./text.txt',  function (err, contents) {
                if (err) {
                     console.log('Error: ', err);
                }
                    uploadFile(contents,cb);
            });
          } ;


async function  uploadFile(fileCont,cb) {
         let dbx =  new Dropbox({ accessToken: APP_KEY });
         await dbx.filesUpload({ path: '/basic4.txt', contents: fileCont })
         .then(function (response) {
           console.log( response);
           cb(response);//Pass response in callback
         })
        .catch(function (err) {
             console.log(err);
         });
}
DriveService.uploadFile(function(success) {//this callback will be called from async 
 return res.status(200).json({success:true,data:success,message:'list of files recived')
})
.catch((error)=>{
    return res.status(400).json({success:false,data:{},message:error.message});
})
```